# Python network/tcp package that integrates in GTK3/PyGObject

Tags: python, network-programming, python-3.x, gtk, pygobject

I am writing an application with Python3 and GTK3 and I need some basic networking library.

Which choices do I have?
Do I need to integrate a package into the gtk main loop or is there some other way?
What about Twisted? Would the in-development python3 support work in my case? (I think Twisted supports gtk main-loop integration?) Is it a good idea to use it already?

Lots of questions :-)

Thanks,
Fabian Henze

Answer (score 1):

[GIO](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/unstable/) is the IO library that GTK+ uses, but I don't see a reason why any other library can't be used. You just need to make sure that all UI changes are done within the GDK lock; the [PyGTK FAQ](http://faq.pygtk.org/) (especially section 20) has some tips for this, although some of it may not be relevant to the new PyGObject.

Comment: GIO does not work, because of a [bug in pygobject](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=621915). I will look into the PyGTK FAQ and will see if that helps